# SQL SUBSTRING to extract all parts of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, substring

I am trying to extract values from a column using the SQL SUBSTRING method. The values from the column are in this format: `VI_{13446F4A-DAC2-44AD-BDAB-86E6F2546DE6}_20220122T090159`.
I am trying to obtain all substrings delimited by the `_` character.
I have managed to extract the first part, but I did not find a way for the others using:

```
DECLARE @Str nchar(200);
SET @Str = 'VI_{13446F4A-DAC2-44AD-BDAB-86E6F2546DE6}_20220122T090159'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str, 1, CHARINDEX('_', @Str) -1) AS F1,
       SUBSTRING(@Str, CHARINDEX('_', @Str)+1, LEN(@Str)) AS F2
```

The code above gives me F1 correct, but F2 is incorrect:

```
F1 = VI
F2 = {13446F4A-DAC2-44AD-BDAB-86E6F2546DE6}_20220122T090159
```

How can I get the other two parts?

Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no inline `.`, I think you could use `PARSENAME`

```
DECLARE @original VARCHAR(255) = 'VI_{13446F4A-DAC2-44AD-BDAB-86E6F2546DE6}_20220122T090159'
DECLARE @new VARCHAR(255) = REPLACE(@original,'_','.')

SELECT PARSENAME(@new,3) as F1,
       PARSENAME(@new,2) as F2,
       PARSENAME(@new,1) as F3
```

Comment: I get NULL for all results.

Comment: @Litwos Then your data is not as you posted or some other issue exists. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6bc911ffa15a16578e359be4382ab084) does exactly what you wrote in your post using your sample data.

Comment: @lptr: yes, i fixed that. It works as expected! Thank you!

Comment: @Litwos, just saw your feedback, sry, guess its working now..